# Which is faster : int comparision vs object comparison

Tags: java, object, optimization, int, compare

In JAVA, I am giving id numbers(int) to my objects. I want to compare whether the given object is the expected object.

Which should I use? Which is faster?

```
if(civ!=this)
```

or

```
if(civ.id!=id)
```

edit:

Extra information:

```
Class Civ {
int id;

public Civ(int i){
id = i;
 }

public boolean checkIfOther(Civ civ){
```

this:

```
  return (civ.id !=id);
```

or this:

```
  return(civ !=this);
```

-

```
}
}
```

Comment: Faster or not, they're two different comparisons.

Comment: For comparing the objects, you can't just compare them using ==. Comparing objects with == only compares both objects are same in memory. You need to override equals method and provide your own logic in that method.

Comment: Why did this get so many downvotes?

Comment: @WVrock [Premature micro optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80094/202153). The performance difference is so small, you'll never notice it. Write the comparison the way it makes most sense. --- Also beware that unless you're *guaranteed* that no two objects in memory can have the same `id` value, the comparisons aren't the same.

Comment: A missed branch can be 10-100x slower making the time doing the comparison almost irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`civ != this` is (<strike>slightly</strike> almost definitely imperceptibly) faster than `civ.id != id`. However, note that the two are only same if `civ` is *coreferent* to `this`. See this example:

```
String a = new String("hello")
String b = a;
a == b // true
String c = new String("hello")
a == c // false!
```

If you are, e.g. loading `civ` from the database, or constructing it from user input, or in any other way creating it aside from direct assignment from `this` (or vice versa), the first method will fail, as they will be two different - even though possibly equal - objects. If uncertain, use `id` to be safe.

Comment: I would replace "slightly" with "almost definitely imperceptibly." This is the level of optimization that one should definitely only attempt once one has measured that it's one of the main performance bottlenecks for your application. It's extremely likely that will never be the case.

Comment: @yshavit: You're completely correct. "slightly" is factually true, but it doesn't at all convey the degree to which the difference is minuscule.

Comment: I am always assigning it as "this". Each object creation is automatically getting different id. So whenever something uses new Civ, it would never have the same id. I am not sure how can ids be same but objects themselves are not but I will use id just to be safe.

Comment: @Amadan, Nice explanation.